# sum up points already in the database with ones being sent

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add points for a user in a database. the way it should work is as follows:
when someone sends another some points, it should calculate the current balance and add the points to the user.

so far i tried but it keeps sending blank figures and mysql isnt adding up those points.

i am including the code also:

```
if(isset($_POST['points'], $_POST['user'])){

include_once("database_connect.php");

$points = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connect, $_POST['points']);
$touser = mysqli_real_escape_string($database_connect, $_POST['user']);
$user = "someone";

$addup = "SELECT amount FROM points (SUM(amount)+SUM('$payment'))";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO currency (amount, from, touser, datemade)       
             VALUES('$addup','$user','$touser','$datemade')";
    $query = mysqli_query($database_connect, $sql); 
    echo "<h1>Thank You</h1><h2>Your payment has been made</h2>";
    exit();}
```

?>
for the web page:
    `<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label for="points">points</label>
      <input type="text" name="points" id="points">
      <label for="user">user</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>`

i look forward for your input.

Comment: This is nonsense. Come on, you can do better. :-)

Comment: Your SQL makes absolutely no sense. You cannot embed a select like that into an insert query. You have multi-level quoting that's going to be utterly broken, killing the ENTIRE insert statement with syntax errors.

Comment: i was under the impression that it needs to call different queries first(seperately) and then blundle them together and save them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in one statement, using `insert . . . select`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO currency(amount, from, touser, datemade) 
          SELECT SUM(amount)+SUM($payment), '$user','$touser','$datemade'
           FROM points"  ;

$ = mysqli_execute($database_connect, $sql);
```

Among the problem with the original query is in the following:

```
SELECT amount FROM points (SUM(amount)+SUM('$payment'))";
```

The `sum('$payment')` is taking the sum of a constant string.  In addition,

Comment: tried that when i click submit it simply refreshes the page. does not get save in the database...